# send array data from ionic 3 app to php page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

please help me with this issue, i'm trying to send data in array form from ionic 3 app and need to receive it in php code

my code:

```
   this.listArray = [
     {'title': 'testTitle'},
     {'body': 'testbody'},
     {'footer': 'testfooter'},
   ];

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body = new FormData();

        body.append("file", this.listArray);

        this.http
        .post("https://android.test.com/test.php", 
         body,options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data['_body']);

          alert("success")

        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert("error")
        });
   });
```

php:

```
 $arrayLength = count($_POST['file']);
    $message = $message."<p> ".$arrayLength."</p>";

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $arrayLength)
    {
           echo $_POST['file'][$i] ."<br />";            $i++;
    }
```

any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: You getting any error?

Comment: in ionic app side no, but when i use count($_POST['file']) in php side, it return 1